# Warnings in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings

Can anyone tell me about the below warning refers to in android eclipse.

"Keybinding conflicts occurred.They may interfere with normal accelerator operation".

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that a shortcut was set for two different actions. If you try to execute the concerning shortcut you will get a little box on the bottom right where you can choose which action you want to execute. So this isn't a serious problem for some actions this makes sense.