# Warning: Keybinding conflicts occurred in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am working with Eclipse ADT, and I keep getting this warning, I really don't know what it is, please help, I am totally a newbie, thank you very much for your time and suggestion.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.jface

Warning
Tue Jul 22 21:41:56 PDT 2014
Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation
```

.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101280/warnings-in-android-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible resolution is
1. Goto Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
2. Type the key shortcut for which the conflict is reported in the "filter" section (for e.g. type 'ALT+SHIFT+Q' in filter)
3. Select the exact key for which conflict is being reported.
4. All the conflicting applications/plugins will be displayed there.
5. Choose the plugin which you do not use frequently and "Unbind" the key for that plugin.

Reference: [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/199958/)

Answer (score 1):

Refer here : http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/199958/
and here : http://www.java-forums.org/android/46959-android-wallopping-my-backside.html

```
One possible resolution is 
1. Goto Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
2. Type the key shortcut for which the conflict is reported in the "filter" section (for e.g. type 'ALT+SHIFT+Q' in filter)
3. Select the exact key for which conflict is being reported.
4. All the conflicting applications/plugins will be displayed there.
5. Choose the plugin which you do not use frequently and "Unbind" the key for that plugin.
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, I am really sure why this happened though

Comment: @NhuyVan: You can accept this as answer by clicking the grey tick mark by the side of this answer.

Comment: btw, Nishanthi is an Indian Girl Name. Just in case, you thought otherwise :D :P

Comment: Oh, haha, sorry, it just came out of my mouth naturally :D